# Database name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library

I am getting following error when I call the `Select` function:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 3
>   ("@SearchTableVar"), row 0, column 0: Data type 0xF3 (user-defined
>   table type) has a non-zero length database name specified.  Database
>   name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only schema name
>   and type name are valid.

**C# code**

```
//DTO
public class SP_SearchEntity_Result
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}

//Businesslogic
public IQueryable Select(int PageIndex, int PageSize, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchBy, List<KeyValuePair<string, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder>> SortBy)
{
    SqlDatabase obj = (SqlDatabase)DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();//System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlServer"].ConnectionString
    return obj.ExecuteSprocAccessor<SP_SearchEntity_Result>("SP_SearchEntity", PageIndex, PageSize, SearchBy.ToDataTable(), SortBy.ToDataTable()).AsQueryable<SP_SearchEntity_Result>();
}

//Extension methods
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> source)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Test");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("KEY",typeof(System.String));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(System.String));

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> data in source)
    {
        var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
        dr["KEY"] = data.Key;
        dr["VALUE"] = data.Value;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dataTable;
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable(this List<KeyValuePair<string, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder>> source)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Test");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("KEY", typeof(System.String));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("VALUE", typeof(System.String));

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder> data in source)
    {
        var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
        dr["KEY"] = data.Key;
        dr["VALUE"] = data.Value == System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder.Ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

The stored procedure returns two tables in result

**SQL proc definition**

```
CREATE TYPE KeyValueTableVariable AS TABLE
(
    [KEY] NVARCHAR(800),
    [VALUE] NVARCHAR(800)
)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SearchEntity
@PageIndex INT=NULL,      
@PageSize INT=NULL,     
@SearchTableVar dbo.KeyValueTableVariable READONLY,
@SortTableVar dbo.KeyValueTableVariable READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
    /*Bla bla bla*/
    SELECT '1' as [ID], 'Nitin' as [NAME]
    SELECT '1' as [COUNT]
END
```

Comment: What is `ToDataTable()`?

Comment: It is Extension method, question is updated

Comment: you might want to rethink your proc names.  This makes for an interesting read http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/still-wrong-to-start-the-name-of-a-user-stored-procedure-with-sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that the xml datatype for stored proc parameters is easier to use.  Rather than casting the parameters to DataTables, you would cast them to XML for the following example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SearchEntity
@PageIndex INT=NULL,      
@PageSize INT=NULL,     
@SearchTableVar xml=NULL,
@SortTableVar xml=NULL
AS
BEGIN
    /*Bla bla bla*/
    SELECT '1' as [ID], 'Nitin' as [NAME]
    SELECT '1' as [COUNT]
END
```

Here's a sample of the KeyValuePair and a query, after it is serialized as XML:

```
declare @sampleXml xml = '
<ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
  <KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
    <key>foo</key>
    <value>bar</value>
  </KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
  <KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
    <key>hello</key>
    <value>world</value>
  </KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
</ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringstring>'

select
        Node.Elem.value('*:key[1]', 'nvarchar(800)') as [Key]
        ,Node.Elem.value('*:value[1]', 'nvarchar(800)') as Value
    from @sampleXml.nodes(N'/*:ArrayOfKeyValuePairOfstringstring/*:KeyValuePairOfstringstring') Node(Elem)
go
```

and a XML Serializer:

```
// from Plinqo: http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks
public static string ToXml<T>(this T item)
{
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, item);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

---

**EDIT :** Returning Multiple Result Sets and Binding them to objects

I'll show you how to do that, but I'm not sure it's what you want to do, based on your mock SQL.  If you are really just returning a count of the objects that were returned, you can count your results after they are IQueryable.

First you'll need a way of binding the objects, which you can get by extending MVC. These model binders expect your query to return column names that match your model properties.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public partial class ModelBinder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Binds the values of an Dictionary to a POCO model
    /// </summary>
    public virtual T BindModel<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        DictionaryValueProvider<object> _dictionaryValueProvider = new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(dictionary, null);
        return BindModel<T>(_dictionaryValueProvider);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binds the values of an IValueProvider collection to a POCO model
    /// </summary>
    public virtual T BindModel<T>(IValueProvider dictionary)
    {
        Type _modelType = typeof(T);
        var _modelConstructor = _modelType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
        object[] _params = new object[] { };
        string _modelName = _modelType.Name;
        ModelMetadata _modelMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => _modelConstructor.Invoke(_params), _modelType);
        var _bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext() { ModelName = _modelName, ValueProvider = dictionary, ModelMetadata = _modelMetaData };
        DefaultModelBinder _binder = new DefaultModelBinder();
        ControllerContext _controllerContext = new ControllerContext();
        T _object = (T)_binder.BindModel(_controllerContext, _bindingContext);

        return _object;
    }
}
```

Example conventions for model binding:

```
public partial class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }
}

public partial class Project 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}   

select 
    1 as [Id]
    , 'NitinJs' as [Name]
    , 5 as [Project.Id]
    , 'Model Binding' as [Project.Name]
    , 2 as [Friends[0]].Id]
    , 'John' as [Friends[0]].Name]
    , 3 as [Friends[1]].Id]
    , 'Jane' as [Friends[1]].Name]
```

Now, you need a method that will read your Data results and bind them to a model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads a record from a SqlDataReader, binds it to a model, and adds the object to the results parameter
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="reader"></param>
/// <param name="modelName"></param>
/// <param name="results"></param>
private void ReadAs<T>(SqlDataReader reader, string modelName, List<T> results, string commandText) 
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        string _key = modelName + "." + reader.GetName(i);
        object _value = reader.GetValue(i);

        if (_result.Keys.Contains(_key))    // Dictionaries may not have more than one instance of a key, but a query can return the same column twice
        {                                   // Since we are returning a strong type, we ignore columns that exist more than once.
            throw new Exception("The following query is returning more than one field with the same key, " + _key + ": " + commandText); // command.CommandText
        }

        _result.Add(_key, _value);
    }

    T _object = new ModelBinder().BindModel<T>(_result);

    if (_object != null)
    {
        results.Add((T)_object);
    }        
}
```

Next, you need a way of getting an open connection to your Database (note: you'll probaly want to grab _dbConnectionString from your config):

```
public SqlConnection GetOpenConnection()
{
    _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectionString); 
    _sqlConnection.Open();
    return _sqlConnection;
}
```

Finally, you need to connect to your database to get your result sets:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a SqlCommand that expects four result sets and binds the results to the given models
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T1">Type: the type of object for the first result set</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T2">Type: the type of object for the second result set</typeparam>
/// <returns>List of Type T: the results in a collection</returns>
public void ExecuteAs<T1, T2>(SqlCommand command, List<T1> output1, List<T2> output2)
{
    string _modelName1 = typeof(T1).Name;
    string _modelName2 = typeof(T2).Name;
    string _commandText = command.CommandText;

    using (SqlConnection connection = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        using (command)
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandTimeout = _defaultCommandTimeout;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())                                               // Call Read before accessing data.
                {
                    ReadAs<T1>(reader, _modelName1, output1, _commandText);
                }

                reader.NextResult();

                while (reader.Read())                                               // Call Read before accessing data.
                {
                    ReadAs<T2>(reader, _modelName2, output2, _commandText);
                }
            } // end using reader
        } // end using command
    } // end using connection
}
```

Then your select method would look more like this:

```
public void SelectInto<SP_SearchEntity_Result, int>(int PageIndex, int PageSize, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SearchBy, List<KeyValuePair<string, System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder>> SortBy, List<<SP_SearchEntity_Result> result1, List<int> result2)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_SearchEntity");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("PageIndex", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PageIndex;
    command.Parameters.Add("SearchTableVar", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = SearchBy.ToXml();

    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SortByCastToString = // modify your ToDataTable method so you can pass a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> for SortBy
    command.Parameters.Add("SortTableVar", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = SortByCastToString.ToXml();

    ExecuteAs<SP_SearchEntity_Result, int>(command, result1, result2); 
}

public void SomeCallingMethod()
{
    List<SP_SearchEntity_Result> _results = new List<SP_SearchEntity_Result>{};
    List<int> _counts = new List<int>{};
    // ...
    // setup your SearchBy and SortBy
    // ...

    SelectInto<SP_SearchEntity_Result, int>(1, 20, SearchBy, SortBy, _results, _counts);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of requirements/limitations for passing Table Valued parameters to [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). See e.g. the example under "Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Stored Procedure":

> The code then defines a `SqlCommand`, setting the `CommandType` property to `StoredProcedure`. The `SqlParameter` is populated by using the `AddWithValue` method and the `SqlDbType` is set to `Structured`.

And note that just using `AddWithValue` is insufficient - the `SqlDbType` has to be changed to `Structured`.

I *believe* that the `ExecuteSprocAccessor` method *isn't* performing this change (or possibly, as in some other examples, where the `TypeName` has to be set to the name of the table type). I can't chase this all through the enterprise library source code, but since I can't find the word "Structured" anywhere in the solution, that's what leads me to this conclusion.

So, if you want to use TVPs, I think you have to abandon the Enterprise Library and write the data access code yourself using `SqlClient` types. (Since you're using TVPs, you're already abandoning the possibility of switching to a different RDBMS anyway).

Answer (score 0):

TVPs as parameters to a stored procedure work for me just fine using Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block v6.0.1304.  My C# code looks like this:

```
public static DataSet SomeHelperMethod(DataTable tvp1, DataTable tvp2)
{
    DbCommand cmd = <SqlDatabase>.GetStoredProcCommand("StoredProcName");

    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@p1", tvp1);
    p1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

    SqlParameter p2= new SqlParameter("@p2", tvp2);
    p2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

    return <SqlDatabase>.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error in 2023 against SQL Server 2017.  The problem was this:

```
        p2.ParameterName = "@list";
        p2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        p2.TypeName = "MYDB.dbo.IntegerList"; // must remove "MYDB." here!
        p2.Value = list;
```